# Time comparison in python if it's in str format

Tags: python, datetime

I have two different values. One value(A) is 2020-03-06T10:00:00+05:30  and another one(B) is 2020-03-03 14:04:02. These two are in str formats. Now I have to compare these two different values as date.If the 'A' is greater than 'B' I have return 'True'

The method I have tired is

```
if A>B:
return True
else:
return False
```

What is happening is if it's greater or smaller it's always going to if statement only.
I am getting A & B from differnet sources and it's in the same format which I have given above.

Comment: Maybe convert them to datetime objects first?

Comment: Why don't you just convert them to datetimes rather than rely on lexicographical ordering?

Comment: Both are in different formats,so I am not sure how to convert it. I tried datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+05:30').But that's not working

Comment: So convert them with two different format strings. I don't see how it's a barrier that they are in different formats